# Add a overlap between image and background

Tags: css, image, overlap

I am having trouble to fix my problem with css.

I have this in my example fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JdLp8/

```
body {
    background: url("http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/gray_jean.png");    
    padding:0;
    height:100%; 
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

.side-image {
    background: url("http://www.achtergronden.info/wp-content/uploads/Natuur-Landschap-achtergrond-23.jpg");    
    width: 200px;
    height: 1000px;
    float: right;
 }
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="side-image">

    </div>
</body>
```

What i want is that the image will overlap smoothly into my body background. I want to remove that hard line between them. I have looked at css gradients but i can't get a gradient over the hard line.

What am i doing wrong? Are gradients the solution for this? Or are there other solutions?

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Update the image to work with the background or update the background to work with the image. All I saw was an image and gray background

Comment: As I understand, you’re trying to do a mask, like a feather effect. Gradients are not designed for this.

Comment: if I understand your question correctly you want the image itself to have a gradient? if so then the easiest solution is to use a transparent PNG.

Comment: Well if you look at the fiddle in the answer of Tommy Brunn below (make sure you watch it in chrome) that is the effect i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-webkit-mask-image` and a gradient to fade the image out. http://jsfiddle.net/TRRG2/2/

```
-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left center, right center, from(rgba(0,0,0,0)), to(rgba(0,0,0,1)))
```

Just know that it will only work in modern browsers. You may also want to look up non-prefixed versions to see if they are available.

Comment: Yeah, I took a quick look at that. It's actually not _as_ bad as I thought.

Comment: Even though it is exactly how i want it to be, it only works in Chrome 36.0 and doesn't work in IE11 and FF 31.0 :(